# App crashing on launch when downloaded from google playstore

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I just deployed my app on the play store. It crashed when users downloaded it and does not open. Here are screenshots from Google's crash report. I don't understand the errors. Please help. [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cICN7.png) and [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaZUh.png)